# MappedSuperclass maps all child entities to one child

Tags: spring, jpa, generics, mappedsuperclass

I have the **TranslationBase** base abstract class, and tow subclasses[entities] : CountryTranslation and RegionTranslation as shown below :

**TranslationBase:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(TranslationBasePK.class)
public abstract class TranslationBase<T> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private T ownerEntity;

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "language_id")
    private Long languageId;

    private String name;
}
```

**CountryTranslation** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country_translation")
public class CountryTranslation extends TranslationBase<Country> {
}
```

**RegionTranslation** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region_translation")
public class RegionTranslation extends TranslationBase<Region> {
}
```

And TranslationBasePK :

```
public class TranslationBasePK implements Serializable {

    private Long ownerEntity;

    private Long languageId;
}
```

On DB i found the id column in CountryTranslation and RegionTranslation tables reference to Country table id !!

I expect CountryTranslation to reference the id of Country and RegionTranslation to reference the id of Region class.

Note : Country and Region have @Id feild named id;

Comment: How does TranslationBasePK look like?

Comment: public class TranslationBasePK implements Serializable {

    private Long ownerEntity;

    private Long languageId;
}

Comment: @SimonMartinelli As above

Comment: If you have an Id Class you must have all attributes in IdClass also in the entity. In your case in TranslationBase http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli
 The problem solved after i created a PK class for every translation class and i annoted them with IdClass

Comment: But i don't think this is the best practice since the PK class is the same for all

Comment: but then IdClass would not work